# How to convert RGBA color codes to 8 Digit Hex in PHP?

Tags: php, colors, subtitle, rgba

I'm attempting to convert some [rgba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_model) values into a format suitable for [SubStation Alpha subtitle files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubStation_Alpha). The `.ass` file format requires a colour format like `&H12345690` where the hex bytes are in blue, green, red, alpha order.

I am finding examples converting 8 digit hex colors into RGBA, but not the other way around. Here is a function I put together based one of the answers, but the alpha channel is always returned as zero:

```php
function rgbtohex($string) {
    $string = str_replace("rgba","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("rgb","",$string);
    $string = str_replace("(","",$string);
    $string = str_replace(")","",$string);
    $colorexplode = explode(",",$string);    
    $hex = '&H';
    
    foreach($colorexplode AS $c) {
        echo "C" . $c . " " . dechex($c) . "<br><br>";
        $hex .= dechex($c);      
    }
    return $hex;
}
```

But if I test it with `rgba(123,223,215,.9)` it produces `&H7bdfd70` which only has 7 characters instead of 8.

Also, the alpha channel (.9) always comes out to zero, so that doesn't appear to be working correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `printf()` family of functions to convert to a properly padded hex string. Decimals cannot be represented in hex, so the value is taken as a fraction of 0xFF.

```php
$rgba = "rgba(123,100,23,.5)";

// get the values
preg_match_all("/([\\d.]+)/", $rgba, $matches);

// output
$hex = sprintf(
    "&H%02X%02X%02X%02X",
    $matches[1][2], // blue
    $matches[1][1], // green
    $matches[1][0], // red
    $matches[1][3] * 255, // adjusted opacity
);
echo $hex;
```

Output:

```
&H17647B7F
```

Comment: Hey @miken32 apparently this format (used for aegisub .ass subtitle files) needs to be in BGR instead of RGB.  Feel free to edit if you want.  I didn't realize this when I posted it. Otherwise your function seems to work well.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the dechex() function to convert each param of your rgba color to a 2 hex digit.

So in your example you have to concat each part of the rgba to get the hex value of your color :
`dechex(123).dechex(100).dechex(23).dechex(0.5*256)`

Notice: The last value can't be used that way. To get a result Opacity (which holds 0 to 1) equals Hex 0 to 255 and thatfor has to be multiplied by 256.

Comment: I tried that and built a function to test, but isn't working.  I added it to the question.  Only produces 7 characters and the alpha channel is always zero.  Thx!